# Include of buildscript repository definition fails

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies

I have multiple files in my gradle build. In one file, I define my repositories. For example, `repos.gradle` looks like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "nexus url"
        }
    }
}
```

Now, in my projects build script, my `project.gradle` looks like:

```
apply from: "repos.gradle"

buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath "some:library:version"
    }
}
```

This fails to build, with an error along the lines of  `unable to add dependency because no repositories are defined`. If I define everything in the `project.gradle` file, everything works.

How can I inherit the repository definition? I have many many projects, and want to use the one definition in case it changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `buildscript` information can't be put into a separate file (here `repos.gradle`) and then imported, it's a special block.

What you can do on the other hand is to put your `buildscript` block into the top level `build.gradle` file and then all other build files from subprojects/inclusion will inherit this block.