# gradle inheritance in multi-module project

Tags: gradle

```
update 05/30/18
```

I think the technical issue is due to the question that ToYonos linked to.

So, let me broaden the non-technical question:

I have a multi-module project with many parts owned by many different people.  We follow similar structures within the modules, but there is no direct inheritance.  Let us say something like:

- module1/

  - java/

    - services/

      - service1/
    - common/

      - library1/
- module2/

  - java/

Each module loosely does the same thing the same way but slightly different ; )  We want to pull out common parts at each layer and put them in a common file but still allow each module to have their own customizations at each layer.

I was hoping 'apply from' could do this, but seems there are limitations (exporting methods, plugins, etc) all due to scoping issues and gradle's top-down command-and-control style.

The one way I see out is through totally yucking up the settings.gradle from this:

```
include ':module1'
include ':module1:java'
include ':module1:java:services'
include ':module1:java:services:service1'
```

To this:

```
include ':root_common'
project(':root_common').projectDir = "$rootDir/common" as File

include ':root_common:module1'
project(':root_common:module1').projectDir = "$rootDir/module1" as File

include ':root_common:module1:module_common'
project(':root_common:module1:module_common').projectDir = "$rootDir/common/module" as File

include ':root_common:module1:module_common:java'
project(':root_common:module1:module_common:java').projectDir = "$rootDir/module1/java" as File

include ':root_common:module1:module_common:java:java_common'
project(':root_common:module1:module_common:java:java_common').projectDir = "$rootDir/common/java" as File

include ':root_common:module1:module_common:java:java_common:services'
project(':root_common:module1:module_common:java:java_common:services').projectDir = "$rootDir/module1/java/services" as File

.... and so on ....
```

This seems rather unmanageable.  Is there a better way?

```
original 05/29/18
```

I have the following that works:

My *build.gradle*:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    ext {
        dockerPluginVersion = '0.19.2'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "gradle.plugin.com.palantir.gradle.docker:gradle-docker:${dockerPluginVersion}"
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.palantir.docker"
apply plugin: "com.palantir.docker-run"

docker {
    ....
}
```

I want other people's *build.gradle*s to be able to use the same configuration as in the above *build.gradle* without copy/paste, so I came up with the following:

Other Person's *build.gradle*:

```
apply from: ${rootDir}/common/docker/build.gradle
```

When I run the above, I get

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Plugin with id 'com.palantir.docker' not found.
```

If I copy/paste only the *buildscript* part of My *build.gradle* to their *build.gradle*, then it works.  So, must be some resolution / ordering issue.

I think the basic question is: how do I apply & configure a plugin from within a *build.gradle* that is itself being treated like a plugin via *apply from* ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include of buildscript repository definition fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49893822/include-of-buildscript-repository-definition-fails)

Comment: Yuck.  Gradle only really supports direct inheritance and composition not so much?

Comment: Use `buildSrc` https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources